# ILocationListener.OnLocationChanged Method never called after RequestLocationUpdates()

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, gps

I was playing with the android gps system following this recipe:
https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/os_device_resources/gps/get_current_device_location/

The OnLocationChanged method is never called so I'm unable to get the gps information (I debugged it using Xamarin Android Player as emulator).
Is there something wrong in the recipe or maybe something that is changed in android to retrieve that kind of information?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure GPS is not enabled in Xamarin Android Player. You'll have to mock out that part of your app, to simulate GPS movement.

Comment: @BjarkeSøgaard: The android device emulated by xamarin android player has gps enabled (I checked like I would have done on my phone), then I checked what parameters are provided by the emulator to the app in the settings (there are latitude, longitude, altitude and precision parameters as shown  [here](http://blog.omniworks.gr/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/blog6_emulatorsettings.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the GPS position through XAP settings.
(See screenshot)

[GPS Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEtev.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a different emulator?
 Geny Motion is quite good for simulating GPS coords check [here](https://docs.genymotion.com/Content/03_Virtual_Devices/Emulating_sensors_and_features/GPS.htm)

[image: GenyMotion GPS settings]

---

Comment: Ok, I tried the app on my phone and the problem doesn't occur. I'll change the emulator asap. Thanks.